# Changing configuration in running Kubernetes Pod

Tags: configuration, kubernetes, apache-nifi, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I have written the `nifi.properties` into a `Kubernetes ConfigMap`. When I deploy NiFi (as a `StatefulSet`) I want to have this `nifi.properties` file to be used by the NiFi I just deployed. To do so I added a volume for the `ConfigMap` and mounted it in the Container. The associated `statefulset.yaml` looks like this:

```
...
containers:
- name: 'myName'
  image: 'apache/nifi:latest'
  ports:
    - name: http
      containerPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
    - name: http-2
      containerPort: 1337
      protocol: TCP
  volumeMounts:
    - name: 'nifi-config'
      mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.6.0/conf/nifi.properties
volumes:
- name: 'nifi-config'
  configMap:
    name: 'nifi-config'
...
```

This doesn't work, I think it is, because NiFi is already running and the `nifi.properties` file is locked by the service. The pod cannot be created, I get an error: `...Device or resource is busy`. I also tried that with the `bootstrap.conf` file, which works, but I don't think that changes in there are recognized by the NiFi service because it would have to be restarted.

I already had the same issue with NiFi deployed on pure Docker, where I worked around by stopping the container, copying the files and starting the container; not very pretty, but working.

Using environment variables to change values in NiFi as stated [here](https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/master/nifi-docker/dockerhub) is also not an option, because the possibility of changing parameters there are very limited.

This problem doesn't occurs for NiFi only. I think that there are many situations where someone want's to change the configuration for a system running within `Kubernetes`, so I hope there is any solution to handle this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with the help of this [helm file](https://github.com/markap14/apache-nifi-helm), but changed it a bit. Actually it is nearly the same as the answer that pepov has given, but as stated in my comment, I got a `CrashLoopBackOff`. This also had nothing to do with the image version, because I used my own image that is based on NiFi 1.6.0 also containing some custom processors.

So my solution is to use the `postStart` handler of Kubernetes. Problem is that it is not guaranteed that this handler is called before the ENTRYPOINT ([see](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#discussion)). But in this case the pod would crash and restart, eventually getting it right; right now I haven't had this problem, so it seems to be good for now.
I copy the content of the `configMap` into a dedicated folder and copy them in the associated NiFi folder in the `postStart` handler.

So here is the `statefulset.yaml`:

```
...
containers:
- name: 'myName'
  image: 'apache/nifi:latest'
  ports:
    - name: http
      containerPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
    - name: http-2
      containerPort: 1337
      protocol: TCP
  volumeMounts:
    - name: 'nifi-config'
      mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.6.0/kubeconfig
  lifecycle:
    postStart:
      exec:
        command:
          - bash
          - -c
          - |
            cp -a /opt/nifi/nifi-1.6.0/kubeconfig/. /opt/nifi/nifi-1.6.0/conf
volumes:
- name: 'nifi-config'
  configMap:
    name: 'nifi-config'
...
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with the above setup:

- You have to specify the subpath to tell which item you mount from the configmap as a single file, see: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44815#issuecomment-297077509
- You cannot mount a configmap item as a readwrite volume by default on 1.9.6 and above, so the start script won't be able to replace properties in it, see: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62099#issuecomment-378809922

To workaround the second issue you can simply mount the configmap item as a separate file (nifi.properties.tmp) and copy it to the destination by wrapping the container entry point with a custom command.

```
...
containers:
- name: 'myName'
  image: 'apache/nifi:latest'
  ports:
    - name: http
      containerPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
    - name: http-2
      containerPort: 1337
      protocol: TCP
  volumeMounts:
    - name: 'nifi-config'
      mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.6.0/conf/nifi.properties.tmp
      subPath: nifi.properties
  command:
  - bash
  - -c
  - |
    cat "${NIFI_HOME}/conf/nifi.properties.tmp" > "${NIFI_HOME}/conf/nifi.properties"
    exec "${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/scripts/start.sh
    # or you can do the property edits yourself and skip the helper script:
    # exec bin/nifi.sh run
volumes:
- name: 'nifi-config'
  configMap:
    name: 'nifi-config'
...
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. But with this approach I get a `CrashLoopBackOff` when creating the container in GKE without any further information (no log data from GKE)

Comment: Not sure, but maybe it's that you don't specify the image version, and apache/nifi:latest is already 1.7.1, so you need to update your mountpath according to that. With the next release NiFi will use a version agnostic path: `/opt/nifi/nifi-current`